# What features of processor is important for programming?

Tags: cpu, java

I want to buy laptop for programming in Java.

And I don't know which features of processor is more important for programming (not gaming!) purposes.

- Is Frequency (MHz) important?
- Is L3 cache (KB) is important?
- Is Hyper-Threaded 2-core processor much slower than processor with 4
  cores (not Hyper-Threaded)?

Usually I'm running:

- Programming IDE (Eclipse / IDEA)
- Application server like Glassfish/JBoss
- Database (e.g. MySQL)
- Web-browser with many opened tabs + Skype

P.S. In fact, I don't know which processor is more suited for me: 
Intel i5 3210M or AMD A10-4600M.  - [Here comparison of processors.](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/816/AMD_A10-Series_for_Notebooks_A10-4600M_vs_Intel_Core_i5_Mobile_i5-3210M_%28PGA%29.html)
Laptop with A10 have slightly powerful configuration. Prices are same.

Comment: This seems like a shopping question and will likley be closed.  Perhaps a rephrase might help

Comment: @DaveM yes, I agree that this question seems like a shopping question. But I tried to make question  objective as much possible, omitting my subjective question in post-scriptum.

Comment: If you are asking if HT cores are faster then non-HT cores it sounds like you have not done research on how IT Hyper-Threading works.  After you dothat your third question will be answered.

Comment: `If you are asking if HT cores are faster then non-HT`  - I wrote in question what I'm asking, if you don't see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably developing on a Linux variant. If that is the case, I would suggest going for the Intel processor, all other things being equal. I get the impression that Intel has greater support for Linux.

See if you can find a processor speed comparison, rather than a feature comparison. Personally, I'd go for at least an i5, with at least four cores at 3.5GHz.

In my experience, the biggest factor after processing speed when deciding to buy a development machine is memory. Try for at least 8GB, and more is better. I know someone with a development laptop that has 24GB in it.

Graphics cards are largely irrelevant, unless you're developing games.

NOTE: These numbers will become ridiculously low after about three months, or when the singularity happens! Yaaay, singularity!